# Merge 2 table-valued-function into one table with different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

To start, I have a `stringSplit()` tabled-value function.

Suppose I have these as parameters:

```
var_1 = 'Apple.jpg,Carrot.png,Fruits.pdf'
var_2 = '9V0I1fab\CvaA5h,IV0asdkas//bVasA,Uasdl00/9asA' //Example base64 formats
```

How would I go so that after using `stringSplit(var_1, ',')`  and `stringSplit(var_2, ',')`? It should merge as one table with different columns,
Say:

```
| name       |       b64        |
---------------------------------
| Apple.jpg  | 9V0I1fab\CvaA5h  |
| Carrot.png | IV0asdkas//bVasA |
| Fruits.pdf | Uasdl00/9asA     |
```

Comment: You wrote your own splitting function - just change it to provide the key (i.e, position) needed to join correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `string_split()` does not guarantee the ordering of the return values.  Nor does it have an option for returning an index number.

If the elements in each string are unique, you can do:

```
select s1.value as name, s2.value as b64
from (select s.value,
             row_number() over (order by charindex(',' + s.value + ',', ',' + @var_1 + ',')) as seqnum
      from string_split(@var_1, ',') s
     ) s1 join
     (select s.value,
             row_number() over (order by charindex(',' + s.value + ',', ',' + @var_2 + ',')) as seqnum
      from string_split(@var_2, ',') s
     ) s2
     on s1.seqnum = s2.seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6d1e7ed44308d8bc1b44bcdbc94b7554) is a db<>fiddle.